# Text on buttons in storyboard and buttons not showing in simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode7

I added two standard UI buttons to the very bottom of a view controller's main view; this is a standard view controller but is segued to from a UICollectionViewController. The overall flow is shown in the screenshot below. I have a navigation controller, a table view controller, a collection view controller and then the standard view controller (far right).

[image]

I can see the buttons I have added in the document outline but on the storyboard as you can see in the second screenshot, the buttons are not showing even though I have set their text (I have highlighted the button on the left to show it is in fact added to the view). I ran the program and it confirms they are not showing. Appreciate your help.

[image]

Edit:- Simulator screen:
[image]

Comment: Have to added the Constraints to the Button?

Comment: This was the second problem - after I removed the bottom bar I set the constraints on the buttons. Everything working now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set **Bottom Bar** to **None** from storyboard AttributedView as shown below[image]

Comment: Tried that and it worked in that I can see the buttons on the storyboard but I don't see them when I run the program. Size classes set to compact regular and running in iPhone 5 simulator.

Comment: can you show the screenshot of simulator screen. . it will help to find what you are doing wrong in autolayout

Comment: edited to show the simulator screen, not sure it will help.

Comment: it looks either you didn't use size classes properly or you didn't add autolayout contraint properly

Comment: u can share the screenshots of constraint it will help to diagnose problem

Comment: I haven't added any constraints yet and have all of the storyboard set to compact regular and simulating on iphone5 so I'm not sure what could be wrong with size classes. There is an image view set above the buttons but it isn't covering them. I will try to add an image now and add constraints relative to image and see how that goes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92494/discussion-between-baydi-and-shinninja).

Comment: if you want to add a bottom bar then you have to choose barButtonItem not a normal UIButton?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a `bottomBar` than you have to add `BarButtonItem` not a normal `UIButton` .

else If you want to add normal `UIButton` than you have to add a custom bottom bar by adding your own `UIView` as bottom Bar and customize as your need.

**NOTE:-** if you don't set you bottom bar to None then, Xcode automatically put your `UIButton` to Bottom bar(Automatically appears).

hope it may help you.